# Rust: How to input a custom string to convert into ciphertext using Kyber1024

Tags: encryption, rust, cryptography

So I would like to make a function in Rust where I can input a string and get the ciphertext out of it. I'm using the Kyber1024 KEM and I can't find a way to input a custom string to turn into a cipher.

Documentation: https://docs.rs/pqcrypto-kyber/0.7.6/pqcrypto_kyber/kyber1024/index.html

Crate: https://crates.io/crates/pqcrypto-kyber

The usage in the documentation just says this:

```
use pqcrypto_kyber::kyber1024::*;
let (pk, sk) = keypair();
let (ss1, ct) = encapsulate(&pk);
let ss2 = decapsulate(&ct, &sk);
assert!(ss1 == ss2);
```

Nowhere does it illustrate (as far as I can see) a way for a user to insert a custom string for example so it can get converted into ciphertext.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The crate [kyber-pke](https://crates.io/crates/kyber-pke) provides functions to encrypt custom messages, but there are some cautions: Kyber-pke uses 3rd-party crate pqc_kyber (the upstream), while the upstream updated pqc_kyber, kyber-pke may not be updated to use newer upstream version; So you need to change Cargo.toml inside kyber-pke to use newer pqc_kyber, hint: kyber-pke 3.0 is licensed under Apache 2.0. And kyber-pke has to append the length of your custom message to the ciphertext, because Kyber1024 uses 256-bit block size to encrypt an AES256 key, kyber-pke appends the plaintext length to the ciphertext for later decryption.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).